# react-native-reanimated not accepting rotation value in degrees

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated

I'm learning reanimated because it works on the UI thread and I want to achieve a rotation animation. Rotating in degrees (like 45deg) is not working and prompts an error. So how can we achieve rotation animation in react-native-reanimation v1(version 1)?

Comment: i m used Math.PI but its not getting proper result

Comment: Can you update your question to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Currently it is not possible to run your code (as you haven't included any), so the ability for anyone to provide meaningful help is limited.

Answer (score 7):

Probably you need `concat` function from reanimated library:

```js
import Animated, { concat } from 'react-native-reanimated';
...
return (
  <Animated.View style={{
    transform: [{rotateZ: concat(yourAnimatedValue, 'deg')}],
  }}/>
);
```

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way for me is doing like this (even if I don't understand why there is no interpolate for input `number[]` to output `string[]`...

```
const animatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    return {
      transform: [{ rotate: `${interpolate(rotation.value, [0, 1], [90, 180])}deg` }],
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

**this [way](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OWsCKJPTZ5g&t=65s) worked with me**

> "react-native-reanimated": "~2.12.0",

```
      let openTabProgress = useSharedValue(0);
    
    //careful next line it is useDerivedValue not useSharedValue

      let iconRotate = useDerivedValue(() => {
        return interpolate(openTabProgress.value, [0, 1], [0, 180]);
      });
    
      const upIconReanimatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
        return {
          transform: [
            {
              rotate: iconRotate.value + "deg",
            },
          ],
        };
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

dont forget to pass as string like `{ transform: [{ rotate: '45deg' }] }` not **rotate: 45deg**

Comment: come friend i was pass string value only my question was its not accepting rotate animation

Comment: by the I was passing like this ==>
  const rotate = interpolate(transition, {
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: ["0deg", "45deg"],
  }); ==>  <Animated.View style={{ transform:[{ rotate }]}} />

Comment: is your component Animated?

Comment: where is the component you want to animate on?