# Using React Reanimated 3, how can I fix "Error: Reading from `_value` directly is only possible on the UI runtime"?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-reanimated

Following along with the react native reanimated docs [here](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/animations#spring) I have this code:

```
import Animated, { useSharedValue, useAnimatedStyle } from 'react-native-reanimated';

function WobbleExample(props) {
  const rotation = useSharedValue(0);

  const animatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    return {
      transform: [{ rotateZ: `${rotation.value}deg` }],
    };
  });

  return (
    <>
      <Animated.View style={[styles.box, animatedStyle]} />
      <Button
        title="wobble"
        onPress={() => {
          rotation.value = withRepeat(withTiming(10), 6, true)

        }}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

But am getting this in my metro console, and the app is crashing

```
Error: Reading from `_value` directly is only possible on the UI runtime

This error is located at:
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:264)
    ...
```

Any suggestions on how to fix are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Here is a related discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62871201/react-native-reanimated-not-accepting-rotation-value-in-degrees

To me it looks like you're accessing the value correctly in the hook.  Are you sure you correctly installed the babel plugins for 'react-native-reanimiated'? If not, it's not going to generate code that calls your your useAnimatedStyle callback on the correct thread.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm also getting the same issue but In my case, I'm importing **Animated** from **react-native** instead of **react-native-reanimated**.

```
import Animated from 'react-native-reanimated';
```

Answer (score 13):

This error also happens when trying to pass the animated style to a regular `View` instead of `Animated.View`.

Answer (score 7):

Similar problem to me, when using the shared value with useAnimationStyle and interpolation.

```
const animatedStyles = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    const Y = energyLevel?.value ?? 5.5;
    const bottomScreen = -height + heightOffset * 2;
    const topScreen = height - heightOffset * 2;
    const offsetY = interpolate(Y, [1, 10], [bottomScreen, topScreen]);
    return {
      transform: [{translateY: offsetY}],
    };
  });
```

but the problem was Animated import:

```
    import Animated from 'react-native-reanimated';
```

Answer (score 4):

I got this error when I had an `Animated` component wrapped in a `ScrollView` and the `stickyHeaderIndices` was trying to make the animated component sticky. For example,

```
  <ScrollView stickyHeaderIndices={[1]}>
    <Text>Some thing</Text>
    <Animated.View style={animatedStyle}>
        ...
    </Animated.View>
  </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue but in my case it was due to importing Animated form 'react-native' and not 'react-native-reanimated'.
Perhaps in your case, trying to set rotation.value outside of a hook is causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was using the wrong version of Reanimated for which version of Expo I was using. Running `npx expo install --fix` fixed the issues for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me the error is caused by this simple syntax mistake, in the Animated.Image

```
 // This is Wrong
 // style={{
 //     imageStyle,
 //      width: imageSize, height: imageSize
 // }}
style={[
    imageStyle,
    { width: imageSize, height: imageSize },
]}
```